# Close shinyWidgets dropdownButton by clicking a button

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to close the context menu of a `dropdownButton` in a shiny app after clicking on a button? I was looking for an attribute like `closed`/`opened` in the `dropdownButton`-documentation and couldn't find anything but I believe there must be a way to do this.

This is an example app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dropdownButton(
    actionButton("button", "Press this Button to close the dropdownButton!"),
    circle = TRUE, status = "primary", icon = icon("user-circle")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(
    input$button, {
      # Set dropdownButton closed
      print("Test")
    }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You need to write some `JS` to control `aria-expanded = "true"`

Comment: @PorkChop Yes, otherwise class of the above div to change dropdown from dropdown open. I tried couldn't do that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyWidgets)

  ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput('help')

  )

  server <- function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(
      input$button, {
        shinyjs::hide("button")
        #output$help <- renderUI({} ) 

      }
    )
    output$help <- renderUI(dropdownButton(
      actionButton("button", "Press this Button to close the dropdownButton!"),
      circle = TRUE, status = "primary", icon = icon("user-circle")
    ) ) 

  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution

Answer (score 1):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput('help')

)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(
    input$button, {
      shinyjs::hideElement("dropdown-menu")


    }
  )
  output$help <- renderUI(dropdownButton(
    actionButton("button", "Press this Button to close the dropdownButton!"),
    circle = TRUE, status = "primary", icon = icon("user-circle")
  ) ) 

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi Alejandro and thanks for your response. Maybe I have to specify my question a bit. I don't want that the button disappears but that the context menu of the `dropdownButton` closes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

By dropping **"sw-show"** class from your dropdown menu, its context will be disappeared.

- Use `shinyjs::removeClass` to do it.
- Don't forget to add **sw-content-** prefix to the menu's ID.

`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  uiOutput('drop_down_output')
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$drop_down_output <- renderUI({
    dropdown( 
      inputId = 'drop_down_1',
      actionButton("button", "Run!")
    ) 
  }) 
  
  observeEvent(input$button,{
    shinyjs::removeClass(id = 'sw-content-drop_down_1', class = 'sw-show')
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

`